# How to track IOPS statistics?

Tags: performance, db2, metrics

Is there a way to access statistics about IO operations per second in DB2 9.7? I am not interested in the buffer pool hit ratio, just IOPS.

Storage managers reported us that a few days ago average IOPS is over 5000  (previously it was 300 they said). I just want to track those numbers which storage managers reported us because I do not want to this problem re-occur.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of looking at physical writes per buffer pool or tablespace over time.  `db2top` will tell you this if you are in Delta mode and look at the "Delta p_reads/s" column.

Comment: DB2 pool physical read != disk I/O operation, not necessarily. It's unknown which of the two Dejan is after.

Comment: @Ian I am not so sure it is Delta p_reads/s column. Storage managers reported us that a few days ago average IOPS is over 5000  (previously it was 300 they said). Now database works just fine, but for your column I see figures between 1500 and 8000 but hitratio is over 90% so buffer pool is doing good job. I am not so convinced that this is statistics I need.. Maybe I am wrong... I just want to track those numbers which storage managers reported us because I do not want to this problem re-occur